# case tool available for

Tags: java, html, oracle, javabeans, case-tools

Is there a any case tool available that support html5 for front end, java for business logic and oracle for database?

Comment: Google input box might be the best forum...

Answer (score 0):

jDeveloper. Although, HTML5 code insight is supported in JDeveloper 12c. See [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/downloads/index-087510.html) for details.

Comment: I am searching for the case tool, like in .Net/C# with SQL Server Database and html5 support in the case tool is called 'Team Foundation server'

but i need to know a tool which work with Java,Oracle DB and html5